# Proportion of numbers larger than an arbitrary number which are not divisible by numbers smaller than that number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to know a concise way to express the proportion of numbers larger than an arbitrary number which are not divisible by numbers smaller than that number.  For example:
f(x) given by the proportion of integers larger than x which are not divisible by integers smaller than or equal to x:
\begin{array}{|c|l|}\hline x&f(x)\\\hline
2& .5\\\hline
3&.333\ldots\\\hline
4&.333\ldots\\\hline
5&.2666\ldots\\\hline
6&.2666\ldots\\\hline
7&.22857\ldots\\\hline
\end{array}
Is there an established name for the function expressed by the second column?  I understand that the prime number theorem basically says that this function converges to zero, but if I'm interested in the function itself and not its limit, I'm not sure what to look at.

Comment: Not sure about what you say about the prime number theorem but I'd say, since there are infinitely many primes that, for each given number $x$, there are infinitely many integers (those primes $p>x$) which are not divisible by any integer $n\leq x$. I'm not sure why you give those values to $f$.

Comment: @Dog_69: Those values look reasonable to me. The OP is asking about the _proportion_ (in a suitable limiting sense) of positive integers not divisible by any integer greater than $1$ and less than, say, $7$. Specifically, we have $f(7)=\frac12\frac23\frac45\frac67\approx 0.22857$.

Comment: @TonyK Okay, so $f$ is the numbers of integers greater than $x$ that are not divisible by any integer less than or equal to over all the integers (I guess) bigger than $x$. Got it.

Comment: Might be worth noting there's probably a relationship here between the mentioned ratio and the Euler Totient function: $\phi(n)$, the number of positive integers less than n which are relatively prime to n.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed So something like $f(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{\phi(x)} \frac{\pi(\phi(x))-1}{\pi(\phi(x))}$ should be fairly explicit, yeah?  There isn't a name for it though, or some way of looking for information about how it behaves?